# UPDATE com duas condições

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gostaria de fazer um `UPDATE` onde tenho duas condições; queria juntar os dois em um só, se não for um é o outro.

PRIMEIRA :

```
UPDATE RLT005
SET CtrDatBaixa = '2018-12-15 00:00:00'
WHERE
CtrDatBaixa BETWEEN '2018-12-15 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-15 23:59:59'
```

SEGUNDA :

```
UPDATE RLT005
SET CtrDatBaixa = '2018-12-31 00:00:00'
WHERE
CtrDatBaixa BETWEEN '2018-12-31 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Descreva o que é juntar em um só. E por que precisa fazer isto?

Comment: O que você deseja é apenas truncar o campo timestamp para apenas a data, zerando a hora, minuto e segundo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicando melhor para um amigo meu, me deu a seguinte sugestão :

```
UPDATE RLT005 
SET CtrDatBaixa = CONCAT(FORMAT(CtrDatBaixa, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), ' 00:00:00')
WHERE DATEPART(DAY, CtrDatBaixa) in (15, DATEPART(DAY, EOMONTH(CtrDatBaixa)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi do *" juntar os dois em um só"*, seria mais ou menos isso:

```
UPDATE RLT005
SET CtrDatBaixa = 
    CASE WHEN CtrDatBaixa BETWEEN '2018-12-15 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-15 23:59:59' THEN '2018-12-15 00:00:00' 
    CASE WHEN CtrDatBaixa BETWEEN '2018-12-31 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-31 23:59:59' THEN '2018-12-31 00:00:00'
    ELSE CtrDatBaixa END
```

Comment: Massa, show de bola !!

Comment: @MarcusCastilho, bom que deu pra ajudar. Mas se a resposta resolveu o problema, vale a pena marcá-la como aceita ([veja porque](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)).

Comment: ah sim, sou novo por aqui.